# nltk pre-processing "stop words/urls"program something wrong in the code

Tags: python, nltk, preprocessor, stop-words

I am doing a Sentiment Analysis for Twitter, and the program almost done but i am facing some problems on the pre-processing, i am trying to filter the documents given, first by removing the "stop words" then remove the tags and urls from the phrase. Can someone tell me in what concern the filtration of stop words and the tags/urls is it correct does it really removing and filtrating any given phrase this is my whole program:

```
import nltk
import pickle
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB
from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
from statistics import mode
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

    def classify(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
        return mode(votes)

    def confidence(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)

        choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
        conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
        return conf

short_pos = open("short_reviews/positive.txt","r").read()
short_neg = open("short_reviews/negative.txt","r").read()

all_words = []
documents = []


allowed_word_types = ["J"]

for p in short_pos.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (p, "pos") )
    words = word_tokenize(p)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w in pos:
        if w[1][0] in allowed_word_types:
            all_words.append(w[0].lower())


for p in short_neg.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (p, "neg") )
    words = word_tokenize(p)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w in pos:
        if w[1][0] in allowed_word_types:
            all_words.append(w[0].lower())

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
filtered_sentence = []
for w in all_words:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
print (filtered_sentence)

filtered_documents = open("pickled_algos/fil_documents.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(filtered_sentence, filtered_documents)
filtered_documents.close()

#remove the words that start with #
filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#', documents.split())

#remove URL
filter(lambda x:x[0]!='https://www.', documents.split())

save_documents = open("pickled_algos/documents.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(documents, save_documents)
save_documents.close()

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)


word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:5000]


save_word_features = open("pickled_algos/word_features5k.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(word_features, save_word_features)
save_word_features.close()


def find_features(document):
    words = word_tokenize(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

save_featuresets = open("pickled_algos/featuresets.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(featuresets, save_featuresets)
save_featuresets.close()

random.shuffle(featuresets)

testing_set = featuresets[10000:]
training_set = featuresets[:10000]


classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
print("Original Naive Bayes Algo accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(15)


def realsenti(text):
    feats = find_features(text)

    return voted_classifier.classify(feats),text
```

and this the part that i want to see if it's really doing the job correct

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
filtered_sentence = []
for w in all_words:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
print (filtered_sentence)

filtered_documents = open("pickled_algos/fil_documents.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(filtered_sentence, filtered_documents)
filtered_documents.close()

#remove the words that start with #
filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#', documents.split())

#remove URL
filter(lambda x:x[0]!='https://www.', documents.split())
```

since i am getting this error everytime

```
filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#', documents.split())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

i hope that everything is clarify and i hope some one will instruct me more from what i did wrong thanks in advance.

Comment: `documents` is a list, would you like to split every item in that list?

Comment: documents it's a list of words ,ummm so should i remove the documents.split()?

Comment: Would you like to split each of the words in that list? If not then remove it.

Comment: when i remove it, it said that i need 2 argument for filter

Comment: I meant remove .split()

Comment: is it correct should i put documents or all_words in there thanks ?